# Shopify Storefront API - productByHandle not returning a product which has just been returned from a previous api call

Tags: shopify

I'm using the iOS sdk to make a call to the Storefront API to get a list of products.

```
{products(first:20,query:"product_type:Mug"){edges{node{title,handle,images(first:1){edges{node{transformedSrc(maxWidth:400,maxHeight:400),originalSrc,altText,id}}}}}}}
```

Which returns the expected list of products.

I'm then making a call to get more information about a specific product from that list:

```
{productByHandle(handle:"handle-from-previous-query"){id,description,images{edges{node{transformedSrc(maxWidth:640,maxHeight:640)}}}}}
```

However, this is returning no product (It's returning this: `<QueryRoot: ["productByHandle": <null>]>`).

I've sanity checked that I'm passing the value from the first api response, and I am. I've also checked that the handle is correct by viewing on the web and it works.

I don't understand this, as the product definitely exists and is visible because it's just been returned from the first api call!

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Dean, my apologies to contact you this way. I'm actually coding a similar application to yours. Populating a dropdown with all products and upon selection of a specific product, output properties of that product. I have everything set up but i'm just missing the link between the selected product, or as you refer to here as "handle:"handle-from-previous-query"". Could you provide some insight on how i should popuplate "handle-from-previous-query" (eg: my selectbox)?

Comment: Hi, (without knowing what language/framework you're using) I would set the id of each entry in the dropdown to it's handle (you can get this from the first query to the api where you get your list of products). Then, when it's selected you have the handle to use to make the second query.

Comment: FYI The best way to get an answer is to ask a completely new question on stack overflow (you can link to this on in your new question), and then put a link to the new question in these comments - that way you get to ask me the question directly, but you're also asking all the other devs in the world :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the `first` operator for images:

```
{
  productByHandle(handle: "handle-from-previous-query") {
    id
    description
    images(first: 100) {
      edges {
        node {
          transformedSrc(maxWidth: 640, maxHeight: 640)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Anyone using 100 product images is doing it weird :)

Comment: @DavidLazar, it's just an example. But they do. Just a product with 10 colours and 5 images colour and here they are 50 images. Add another option (visual) and you'll hit 100 ;)

Comment: I understand 100 variants. So you could have 1 per variant. So sure. And the product might have 5-10 itself. Sure.. So yes, one could make a call and expect that much data, But usually GraphQL limits on that make you page out expensive resources. I never use Storefront API but I know the Admin one has real problems dishing out a first: 100 on anything without blowing chunks.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaarg, that's what I get for trying to code at night. It even said that in the error parameter, but I wasn't checking because `result` wasn't `nil`.